# Used ASP membership in past and now want to go to MS Azure and I don;t know where to start

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have a web form application (asp.net vb back) running membership and roles on SQl Server (hosted on godaddy). It works fine. Godaddy has an ASP.net schema option when setting up the SQL server, which was great for me using Visual Studio. The wizard set up membership and roles no problem (I code as a hobby and just learning). Now that the demands on the app are too much for Godaddy, I am looking at MS Azure; however, from what I read, Azure doesn't support classic asp membership/roles . I have found reference to custom scripts that can be installed, but those links are now broken e.g. 
[like this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mszcool/archive/2010/02/10/sql-azure-make-asp-net-membership-and-roles-api-work-on-your-cloud-database.aspx)

My question is: If I were to start a new webform app that provides membership / roles via some sort of Visual Studio wizard, what type of project should I use? ASP.NET mvc3,4 ? Does this require great changes? Or, should I forget about a new type of project and just look at finding a SQL server host that is better than Godaddy but still supports classic asp schema?

Sorry for the basic nature of the question.

Comment: "Azure doesn't support classic asp membership/roles" Wait, what? Why not? It's an SQL Server database at heart, that's all you really need.  A Web Forms app is NOT an MVC app, they are different (though you can use them in the same project). That said, if you do start a new MVC project, might as well use the latest version of MVC (5). Also, is your existing site really [Classic ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_server_pages) or is it [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asp.net)?

Comment: Also, the latest authorization system is [Identity 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx) if you're starting a new project and want to use current technology. And there is no longer any built-in Visual Studio system for managing Identity, but you might check out [Thinktecture Identity Manager](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, yes, the web app is asp.net. I signed up for Azure, but there is no option for a asp.net schema pre-made, so to speak. People have made a schema for roles and membership, like this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006191 but the scripts do not seem to be available anymore. The scripts for supporting state session were available, but not the role/memberships. I guess I was looking for something like the asp.net login wizard that worked so easily in Visual Studio 2013 Web with the ready asp.net schema on GoDaddy.

Comment: actually, I found a download site for the asp.net azure scripts: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=23443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you look at *Identity* for your new membership system - it is *Code-First* so will work great for spinning up new instances without a complicated setup procedure. That being said, if you need to **port** your existing application to Azure you have two options:

1. Run an Azure Virtual Machine and install your SQL database on it (using MS SQL Server, any flavor you choose, or MySQL or whatever your existing app uses) -- you can run your website on this VM as well or run the website using Azure Websites which would allow for easier scaling, etc.
2. Use SQL Azure and convert the membership tables, stored procedures, etc. to run on SQL Azure. There are a number of significant changes that would have to be made based on differences between MS SQL and SQL Azure (and some limitations) but I have done this successfully for an older project (which I'm now refactoring to use *Identity* -- get the idea? Best to modernize the app to use a supported membership system)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've used that aspnet_regsqlazure script that you found. I remember having some minor problems and ended up modifying the source after finding and correcting issues with the implementation for my purposes. I much prefer the new *Identity* system (not difficult to learn or to merge into your code) so I don't have to worry about running a script before attempting to deploy. Here's a Microsoft article on migrating an existing website from SQL Membership to Identity that might help: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity